# Does the maximum modulus principle hold for general analytic sets?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables, maximum-principle

Let $U \subset \mathbb C^n$ be a domain and $X \subset U$ a connected analytic subset. Does the maximum modulus principle hold for $X$? That is, if I have a holomorphic function $f : U \to \mathbb C$ whose modulus attains a maximum value on $X$, is $f$ then constant on $X$?

(Obviously, this is true if $X$ does not have singularities, because then $X$ is itself a complex manifold. But what if $X$ does have singularities?)

Comment: @user1090793: The real line is not an analytic subset of the complex plane. An analytic subset is a closed subset which is locally the zero set of a finite number of holomorphic functions.

Comment: ah, I see. Not so simple then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the maximum modulus principle holds for $X$. See Gunning and Rossi, “Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables”, chapter III, theorem B.16, p. 106:

> **16. Theorem.** Let $V$ be a connected subvariety of the domain $U$ in $\mathbb C^n$. If $f$ is holomorphic in $U$, and its modulus attains a maximum in $V$, then $f$ is constant on $V$.

Comment: @isekajin Is the modulus taken for $f|_V$ or $f$?

Comment: @Curious: For $f \mid_V$.